# Auto height grid

Tags: javascript, css, grid, jquery-masonry

I have a product grid on my e-shop (http://shop.rukahore.sk/). Every product div is 222px x 222px, but I want it to have auto height.

I tried something like this - http://patterntap.com/code/stacking-columns-layout-masonry , 
but I had to add min-height and it didn't look good because some of the images were smaller or bigger and wrapping div was still 222px, which I don't want to happen due to hover effect, etc.

Can someone provide advice regarding this?

Comment: instead of div why cant you use a particular width and height for the image..

Comment: What do you mean, Arun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for using the display shown in that page you need to use the plugin

```
<!-- Requires Masonry | visit http://masonry.desandro.com/ to download -->
```

If you don't want to add more plugins... Well, what makes you lose the height is the float css property. You should use other thing to make the grid, see for example how they do it in www.camarasdecolores.com.

To add the Masonry plugin:

Add an id to your container:

```
<div id="masonryContainer" class="hp-products allposts" style="position: relative; height: 2008px;">
```

Add the init js code in a script

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#masonryContainer').masonry({  
    itemSelector: '.hp-product',
    columnWidth: 60
  });  
});
```

change some css:

```
#masonryContainer { width: 0 auto; }

.hp-product {
    width: 180px; float: left;  
}
.hp-product-img {

}
.hp-product-img img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
//Void the following ones
    .hp-products {
    }
    .allposts {
    }
    .allposts .hp-product {
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but Masonry plugin doesn't solve my problem with min-height for wrapping div. If I remove this property, all images are collapsed.

Comment: Hi Robert. Doing all that it works. Maybe you tried before without removing your css with information about sizes. As these plugins use to calculate positions when the page is loaded this css affect them

Comment: Just to be sure - I ment min-height of wrapping div of every product, not wrapping div of whole page or products.
Thank you for your code, I'll give it a try! :-)

Comment: Yes, if look at the code I posted now .hp-product has only width and float. Not height or min-height.